# Send alert on failure of webjobs in azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-continuous

There is one requirement to send an email upon unsuccessful web-jobs only. There are 16 web-jobs which are deployed and running successfully on azure portal. I have suggested to modify the code for existing web-job but client does not want to modify web-jobs. He wants to add something extra which does not require to modify web-jobs anymore. I am confused, without modifying web-jobs, how can I send an email? I searched a lot on google and stack-overflow but didn't get anything.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Is your ask related to how to create alerts if the azure function app fails to run and send the email?

Comment: Not azure function, I have created azure webjobs and deployed it successfully in azure app service. Need to send an email if azure webjobs fails, but dont want to modify the webjobs.

Comment: Can you poll the REST API?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get-triggered-web-job-history

Comment: {
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationFailedInvalidHeader",
        "message": "Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is provided in an invalid format."
    }
}

Comment: getting error while calling from postman. where can I get authorized access token?

Comment: Yes Now I am able to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

**Few of the workarounds for getting the notification to email for WebJobs Status:**

- Using `ErroTrigger` and `SendGrid` extensions. you can do the Notifications sending to email for the WebJob SDK.
- check this article on how to set that up which uses both extensions to send an email if an error occurred 10 times in 30 minutes window with a throttle up to 1 hour.

```cs
public static void ErrorMonitor(
    [ErrorTrigger("0:30:00", 10, Throttle = "1:00:00") TraceFilter filter,
    [SendGrid] SendGridMessage message)
{
    message.Subject = "WebJobs Error Alert";
    message.Text = filter.GetDetailedMessage(5)
}
```

If you aren't using the WebJob SDK, then unfortunately there aren't any events for continuous webjobs. There is [only one for triggered jobs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/3f22884d322d5a56fa85569fec8bd1b4f4c132ae/Kudu.Core/Jobs/TriggeredJobsManager.cs#L250-L260).

**Also, visit this [MSFT Doc](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip31.html) and [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802834/how-to-get-azure-web-job-running-alert-in-mail-from-azure-portal) for information on setting up the email alerts with App Services.**